# Same style applied to different media queries

Tags: html, css

I am working on a template, where i applied media queries for range 768px to 1024px and includes it in my html file, and applied another set of media queries for the range 425px to 750 px and included it in html file. But the styles applied for the range 728px-1024px is applied for both the ranges.

```css
/* mediumdevice.css */

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
  /*some code */
}


/* small.css */

@media only screen and (min-width:425px) and (max-width:750px) {
  /*some code */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="mediumdevice.css">
```

Comment: Your codes, both are the same!!

Answer (score 0):

In your above question both the media queries contains same screen size check that first. If still it's not working means try the below way.

Style that what you have applied for 425px to 750 px screen apply with `!important` property.

For example

```
/* small.css */
@media only screen and (min-width:425px) and (max-width:750px)
{
.paragraph
 {
   font-size : 20px !important
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your full code, Is the screen sizes are correct? and when running the code clear browser cache and run

Answer (score 0):

Change the sequence of your `css` file link. The `small.css` should be placed after `mediumdevice.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="mediumdevice.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="small.css">
```

Comment: Still not working. I also tried placing css file links below bootstrap link files. Does overriding bootstrap styles affect media queries

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: The problem was with chrome dev tool.I  tried the same code snippet with firefox it was working fine. Thanks!